# The location of an element nested in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion, hash

I have an array of hashes whose values are arrays of hashes:

```
org_array = []
#Create Parents
org_array.push(:org_name => "Parent 1", :org_id => "123ABC", :org_parent_id => nil,     :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array.push(:org_name => "Parent 2", :org_id => "456ABC", :org_parent_id => nil, :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array.push(:org_name => "Parent 3", :org_id => "789ABC", :org_parent_id => nil, :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array.push(:org_name => "Parent 4", :org_id => "1011ABC", :org_parent_id => nil, :children => [], :status => "created")
#Create Children
org_array[0][:children].push(:org_name => "Child1", :org_id => "1234ABC", :org_parent_id => "123ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[0][:children].push(:org_name => "Child2", :org_id => "5678ABC", :org_parent_id => "123ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[0][:children].push(:org_name => "Child3", :org_id => "91011ABC", :org_parent_id => "123ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[1][:children].push(:org_name => "Child1", :org_id => "1213ABC", :org_parent_id => "456ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[1][:children].push(:org_name => "Child2", :org_id => "1415ABC", :org_parent_id => "456ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
#Create Grandchildren
org_array[0][:children][0][:children].push(:org_name => "Granchild1", :org_id => "1617ABC", :org_parent_id => "1234ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[0][:children][1][:children].push(:org_name => "Granchild2", :org_id => "1617ABC", :org_parent_id => "5678ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[0][:children][2][:children].push(:org_name => "Granchild3", :org_id => "1819ABC", :org_parent_id => "91011ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[1][:children][0][:children].push(:org_name => "Granchild1", :org_id => "1920ABC", :org_parent_id => "1213ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
org_array[1][:children][1][:children].push(:org_name => "Granchild2", :org_id => "2122ABC", :org_parent_id => "1415ABC", :children => [], :status => "created")
```

The following code returns the object and the key:

```
def nested_hash_value(obj, key, value)
  if obj.respond_to?(:key?) && obj.key?(key) && obj.has_value?(value)
    return obj[key]
  elsif obj.respond_to?(:each)#checks to see if its an array
    r = nil
    obj.find{ |*a|r=nested_hash_value(a.last ,key, value)}
    r
  end
end

nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "2122ABC")
```

but I want it to return the location of the object, something like `org_array[1][:children][1][:children][0]` instead of the value of `2122ABC`.

Comment: I think you should explain why / what you want to do with that.  It maybe be better to get the object's id, and then be able to re-reference it later

Comment: I want to be able to locate the object to update the status key, or to be able to push more org's as children orgs to to any parent/children/grandchildren orgs regardless where the org is as long as I have the org_id.

Comment: Re your comment on my answer, I don't understand how you are using `inject`, considering that it takes a block and an optional initial value as an argument.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a few suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def nested_hash_value(arr, key, val, path_arr = [])
  return nil if arr.empty?
  arr.each_with_index do |h,i|    
    return path_arr << i if h.key?(key) && h[key] == val
    if h.key?(:children) && rv = nested_hash_value(arr[i][:children], \
        key, val, path_arr.dup << i << :children)
      return rv
    end        
  end
  return nil
end  

p nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "2122ABC")
  # => [1, :children, 1, :children, 0]
p nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "1819ABC")
  # => [0, :children, 2, :children, 0]
p nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "789ABC")
  # => [2]
p nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "91011ABC")
 # => [0, :children, 2]
```

Since you are new to Stackoverflow (SO), I would like to offer a few suggestions on the formulation of your question, which you may wish to apply in future:

- remove all hash fields that are not central to the question;
- reduce the number of children and grandchildren to the minimum needed for illustration; and
- rather than display code that constructs the array, display the array itself, in a way that clarifies its structure.

Applying these principles, you might start with the following:

```
org_array =
  [{:org_id=>"123ABC", :org_parent_id => nil, :children =>
      [{:org_id=>"1234ABC", :org_parent_id=>"123ABC", :children =>
          [{:org_id=>"1617ABC", :org_parent_id=>"1234ABC", :children => []}]
        },
        {:org_id=>"5678ABC", :org_parent_id=>"123ABC", :children =>
          [{:org_id=>"1617ABC", :org_parent_id=>"5678ABC", :children => []}]
        }
      ]
    },
    {:org_id=>"456ABC", :org_parent_id => nil, :children =>
      [{:org_id=>"1213ABC", :org_parent_id=>"456ABC", :children =>
          [{:org_id=>"1920ABC", :org_parent_id=>"1213ABC", :children => []}]
        },
        {:org_id=>"1415ABC", :org_parent_id=>"456ABC", :children =>
          [{:org_id=>"2122ABC", :org_parent_id=>"1415ABC", :children => []}]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

If a line is too long to display if fully with horizontal scrolling, insert a line continuation character. Pretend this line was really long if not continued:

```
   {:org_id => "1415ABC", :org_parent_id => "456ABC", \
      :children =>
```

You might consider defining `orig_arr` in your code like this, rather than having all the push statements (unless it is being constructed dynamically, of course).

Now let's consider whether it might be helpful to change the structure of your array `org_array`. Considering that the array indices really serve no useful purpose, you might consider making it a hash of hashes of hashes, with the hash keys `:org_id`. (Note that Grandchild1 and Grandchild2 have the same `:org_id`. That's not a problem, since their parents (Child1 and Child2) have different keys, but I don't know if you intended that.)

The back-references to parent ids is generally not necessary, as the latter are either available when you need them, or can be computed easily on the fly.  You might consider a hash like the following, which contains all of the information fields that were in your `org_array`:

```
org_hash =
  {"123ABC" => {:org_name => "Parent 1", :status => "created", :children =>
     {"1234ABC" => {:org_name => "Child1", :status => "created", :children => 
        {"1617ABC" => {:org_name => "Grandchild1", :status => "created"}}},
      "5678ABC" => {:org_name => "Child2", :status => "created", :children =>
        {"1617ABC" => {:org_name => "Grandchild2", :status => "created"}}}}},
   "456ABC" => {:org_name => "Parent 2", :status => "created", :children =>
     {"1213ABC" => {:org_name => "Child1", :status => "created", :children => 
        {"1920ABC" => {:org_name => "Grandchild1", :status => "created"}}},
      "1415ABC" => {:org_name => "Child2", :status => "created", :children =>
        {"2122ABC" => {:org_name => "Grandchild2", :status => "created"}}}}}
  }
```

Would defining `org_hash` like this make life easier for you?

As an aside, you might familiarize yourself with one of the "pretty-print" gems that do the work of formatting complex objects such as `org_array` and `org_hash`.  One such gem is [Awesome Print](http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html), which you would invoke as follows:

```
require 'ap'
ap org_hash
```

It would display the following (which I've truncated after Parent 1):

```
{
    "123ABC" => {
        :org_name => "Parent 1",
          :status => "created",
        :children => {
            "1234ABC" => {
                :org_name => "Child1",
                  :status => "created",
                :children => {
                    "1617ABC" => {
                        :org_name => "Grandchild1",
                          :status => "created"
                    }
                }
            },
            "5678ABC" => {
                :org_name => "Child2",
                  :status => "created",
                :children => {
                    "1617ABC" => {
                        :org_name => "Grandchild2",
                          :status => "created"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: This works! In order to update the values of the search results I'm using the inject command for example this would change the name of the org_name for the record found `p.inject(org_array, :fetch)[:org_name] = "New Name"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider passing the keys needed to produce the current 'position' in your data-structure

```
def nested_hash_value(obj, key, value, keychain=[])
  keychain << key

  if obj.respond_to?(:key?) && obj.key?(key) && obj.has_value?(value)
    return keychain
  elsif obj.respond_to?(:each)  # checks to see if its an array
    r = nil
    obj.find{ |*a| r=nested_hash_value(a.last ,key, value, keychain) }
    r
  end
end

nhv_result = nested_hash_value(org_array, :org_id, "2122ABC")
```

---

*note: I thought this would output something like*

```
#=> nhv_result
[1, :children, 1, :children, 0]
```

but it does not, yet.  I'm working on a refinement, but this is clearly a viable approach

---

Then your result is a descriptor for how to locate that value again

```
nhv_result.reduce(org_array) {|acc, key| acc = acc[key] }
```

Comment: I agree, but I tried something like that and I got the same result that this code generated: org_id org_id org_id ...